# Thunderbird-3 keeps on downloading already downloaded messages again?

Tags: gmail, imap, thunderbird

I am using Thunderbird for my gmail account, with IMAP settings. All my folders are synchronized. A very strange behavior, after all my mails are downloaded, TB3 starts downloading email again. At times saying "downloading x out of y messages" where x > y (like now downloading 19 out of 11 messages). Had the same problem in TB3 for windows so, replaced TB with Outlook-07, issue resolved. But on linux, I dont like the evolution's interface, so i have no choice but to stick to TB. Any suggestions how to TB not eat my bandwidth.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling TB3 yet?  Sounds like a bug to me.  Perhaps check out the Thunderbird boards to see if any existing bugs exist with this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I read on some forum, gmail uses "ALL mails" folder. Thunderbird subscription system download both the mails, so i the subscription list I unchecked the All Mails and left inbox checked. This solved mine problem, I hope that was it.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in 2016-2017 with Gmail and no All Mails folder showing at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file called `popstate.dat` in thunderbird. It seems to keep track of msgs it has already downloaded from your webprovider's mail server. So, that each time you access this server. It shouldn't dowload the emails again that you got "the last time" you accessed it.

The solution may have something to do with "gmail merged emails" or something.

**This is what worked for me:**

I used [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/), and I found that I had several copies of the `popstate.dat` file on my drive...

I deleted all of them *except for the oldest one* which probably was created by my "very first installatin" of Thunderbird... And that solved the problem!

(I also got the Thunderbird add-on for duplicate files to "find and erase" thousands of dupe emails. Much easier and much faster then doing manually, etc...)

That's it: Just "delete dupe copies of "popstate.dat". I kept the "oldest one" since I figured some other program "had created the newer duplicate ones"

Also, the download of emails from the comcast server is "very much faster". Without the extra copies of that file probably fighting with one another.

Comment: The asker was using IMAP though, not POP. I too see this happening with IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this http://kb.mozillazine.org/Duplicate_messages_received

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.